# How page allocation works when availablility of pages in specific migration_type freelist is less than the requested no. of pages?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, arm, kernel, allocation

I am trying to understand the page allocation procedure in details and found below sequence for that:

> __alloc_pages_nodemask()
>
> -> get_page_from_freelist()
>
> -> buffered_rmqueue()
>
> -> __rmqueue()
>
> -> __rmqueue_smallest()   // if this will fail call goes to __rmqueue_fallback()

`__rmqueue_fallback()` api's depends on `fallbacks[][]` below.

```
static int fallbacks[MIGRATE_TYPES][4] = {
    [MIGRATE_UNMOVABLE]   = { MIGRATE_RECLAIMABLE, MIGRATE_MOVABLE,     MIGRATE_RESERVE },
    [MIGRATE_RECLAIMABLE] = { MIGRATE_UNMOVABLE,   MIGRATE_MOVABLE,     MIGRATE_RESERVE },
#ifdef CONFIG_CMA
    [MIGRATE_MOVABLE]     = { MIGRATE_CMA,         MIGRATE_RECLAIMABLE, MIGRATE_UNMOVABLE, MIGRATE_RESERVE },
    [MIGRATE_CMA]         = { MIGRATE_RESERVE }, /* Never used */
#else
    [MIGRATE_MOVABLE]     = { MIGRATE_RECLAIMABLE, MIGRATE_UNMOVABLE,   MIGRATE_RESERVE },
#endif
    [MIGRATE_RESERVE]     = { MIGRATE_RESERVE }, /* Never used */
#ifdef CONFIG_MEMORY_ISOLATION
    [MIGRATE_ISOLATE]     = { MIGRATE_RESERVE }, /* Never used */
#endif
};
```

Please explain the usage of array in details.

I found this from the comment above the declaration:

> "This array describes the order lists are fallen back to when the free
> lists for the desirable migrate type are depleted."

Comment: If there is no requested migration type pages It allocates from different migration types specified in array...